# Finding Min and Max rows of a column and subtracting the values of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'regionname' : [10022, 10128, 10022, 10022, 10128],
              'date' : ['1996-04-01', '2005-01-01', '2014-05-01', '2006-04-01', '2017-06-01', '2017-06-01'],
              'median_price': [np.nan, 257700.0, 407100.0, 500000.0, 750000.0, 325000 ]})

-----------------------------------------
Output:

regionname  date        median_price
0   10022   1996-04-01  NaN
1   10128   2014-05-01  407100.0
2   10022   2006-04-01  500000.0
3   10022   2017-06-01  750000.0
4   10128   2017-06-01  325000.0
```

Every `regionname` corresponds to a zip code in the data set. If it helps, the data was originally wide format where every date from 1996-04 to 2017-06 contains the median price that I melted into long form.

I want to find the minimum date with a `median_price` and subtract it from the max date (2017-06-01) to examine the rate of change. Every `regionname` (zip code) has data for the max date but the min dates vary. I have come across some posts on here that suggested doing a groupby but haven't been able to make that post work. In my case, `grp = df.groupby('regionname')`.

My goal is to calculate the change in a new column or through aggregation. I have tried something like this but `dropna()` does not work on a groupby then I could subtract the max.

```
min_test = df.groupby(['regionname','date'])['median_price'].dropna().min()

max_test = df.groupby(['regionname','date'])['median_price']
```

*Sample expected output could be something like this:*

```
regionname  change     
0   10022   250000.0
1   10128   -82100.0
...
```

There are 25 unique zip codes in the data and the dates range from 1996-04-01 to 2017-06-01 so this should cover at least the basic output options.

I am not sure if I could use `np.nanmin` or what the best approach would be. I feel like there is a simple approach I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First idea is use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by both columns and then subtract first and last value, it working correct, because by default are removed missing values:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = df.sort_values(['regionname','date'])
g = df.groupby(['regionname'])['median_price']

df['change'] = g.transform('last') - g.transform('first') 
df = df.sort_index()
print (df)          
   regionname       date  median_price    change
0       10022 1996-04-01           NaN  250000.0
1       10128 2014-05-01      407100.0  -82100.0
2       10022 2006-04-01      500000.0  250000.0
3       10022 2017-06-01      750000.0  250000.0
4       10128 2017-06-01      325000.0  -82100.0
```

Or you can use difference of index values by [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) and [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html), but unfortunately missing value is not omitted, so necessary first by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and then created new value column by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

g = (df.dropna(subset=['median_price'])
       .set_index('median_price')
       .groupby(['regionname'])['date'])
df['change'] = df['regionname'].map(g.idxmax() - g.idxmin())

print (df)       
   regionname       date  median_price    change
0       10022 1996-04-01           NaN  250000.0
1       10128 2014-05-01      407100.0  -82100.0
2       10022 2006-04-01      500000.0  250000.0
3       10022 2017-06-01      750000.0  250000.0
4       10128 2017-06-01      325000.0  -82100.0
```